# core-data is getting old data and not the updated values

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I am having this strange issue which has been plaguing me all day, i am updating an object in a background thread which is saving correctly

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest1 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            NSEntityDescription *entity1 = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"STMilestone"
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:tmpContext];
            [fetchRequest1 setEntity:entity1];
            [fetchRequest1 setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
            NSError *error;
            NSString *idNum = [obj valueForKey:@"id"];
            //                    NSUInteger TrackerExists = [tmpContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest1 error:&error];
            [fetchRequest1 setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identiferNumber = %@", idNum]];

NSArray *logs = [tmpContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest1 error:&error];
NSManagedObject *updateObj = [logs objectAtIndex:0];
[updateObj setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:20] forKey:@"progress"];
```

When i then get this object in the same background thread this gets the correct updated value

However when i go to get this updated value on my main thread it returns the old value, then when i clear the cache and reload the app it pulls the correct data

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"STTracker"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]];
```

I think this may be a context issue, my background thread context is being created with this

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *tmpContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
tmpContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = [appDelegate persistenceCoordinator];
```

and the main thread is

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistenceCoordinator];
if(coordinator != nil)
{
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    NSUndoManager *undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
    [undoManager setGroupsByEvent:NO];
    [_managedObjectContext setUndoManager:undoManager];
}
[_managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];
```

However i have updated other objects in my app and they are being pulled through, so any help or insight on why this might be happening would be great

Comment: Are you calling save on the NSManagedObjectContext?

Comment: Yes i am, the data is being save into the database, I have done the save then opened up the database in a sqlite editor and the saved data is in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work:
`NSManagedObjectContext *tmpContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];`

You need to need to init the context with the right concurrency type and assign it the correct parent context (or persistent store coordinator). See the docs

- [initWithConcurrencyType:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-SW40)
- [setParentContext:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-SW42)

When child and parent contexts are set up correctly, you an `save` the child context which does not really write to the persistent store but just "pushes" the changes up to the parent context. The changes are written to the store once you save the parent context again.

Comment: Yes i am setting the persistentStoreCoordinator, i didn't add it in when i wrote the question, i've updated the question to reflect this

Comment: Two things: you are still not using concurrency type and you are maybe not saving in the parent context.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by concurrency type, I am new to using core data, could you please explain further and possibly provide an example?

Comment: I have read through the documentation, and am I correct by what you ment is using the performBlockAndWait method as I think I am doing the rest of the best practices its doing.However when I add in the performBlockAndWait method it returns an error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can only use -performBlockAndWait: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.'

Is this what you ment for me to try or am i missing something?

Comment: I have fixed the issue, the context that was pulling down the new values seems it was being cashed, i have fixed it by refreshing the context with a new one when displaying the values, this is probably not the best way to fix this issue but this works for me, thanks for the help Mundi :)